# Angular use different injection token conditionally in module from routing module

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, provider, injection-tokens

I want to use different value for a injection token in a module conditionally, something like:

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ABC_TOKEN,
      useValue: useA ? a : b,
    },
  ],
```

how to do that?
and also I want to pass the `useA` from a routing module which maybe something like:

```
      {
        path: 'abc',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../abc.module').then(
            (m) => m.AbcModule,
          ),
        data: {
          useA: true,
        },
      },
```

So what I want is based on the data in the routing module, I want to use different value of injection token for the module

Thanks.

Comment: Is `ABC_TOKEN` only consumed in `AbcModule` or elsewhere as well?

Comment: which angular version you're using?

Comment: It will be consumed in several modules

Comment: I am using angular 13

Comment: Okay, no issues, you can set the default value in `app.module.ts` by configuring it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to decide the value of `ABC_TOKEN` injection token, consider using `useFactory` function. And define that in your `AbcModule` module.

```
providers: [
   {
      provide: ABC_TOKEN,
      useFactory: (route: ActivatedRoute) => {
        // below can be improved. 
        let useA = route.firstChild.firstChild.snapshot.data['useA'];
        return route.data['useA'] ? a : b;
      },
      deps: [ActivatedRoute],
   },
],
```

On catch is, you have to access the parent route `data` from the current activatedRoute. For that, you may have to traverse. or two steps back using `route.firstChild.firstChild.snapshot.data['useA']`. Also, this can be written using a recursive function.

I've created a Demo for you on this. Navigate to the product-list page and check code inside `ProductModule`

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-lazy-loading-i8rwed)